# Spring: avoid logins during night/weekend for non-admin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are working on an authentication system, using Spring 5 (I'm new at using this Framework).

We use `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, and, for security reasons, I have to extend the system to avoid that non-admin user could log in during weekends, or during certain non-working hours.

I was checking on the documentation, this site, and the Web, the only thing I found that gave me ideas is `@PreAuthorize`, but I could not find the way to use it for my purpose.

Can it be done using any annotation or some way provided by any framework?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to prevent login attempts to your system at specific time in day ? I remember that `@PreAuthorize` restrict to access specific functions based on user_role

Comment: You may need to write a filter extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` to override `attemptAuthentication` method with you logic here and add this filter to your `WebSecurityConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@PreAuthorize` to protect methods by role as usual. For example in a REST controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ORDINARY_USER')")
@GetMapping(value="/mymethod")
public void myMethod() {
...
}
```

Don't forget `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` on your main class.

In your `UserDetailsService` where you build a `UserDetails` object upon login, do not assign a role to a non-admin user if out of hours.

This will also work for long-lived tokens such as a JWT because you get to build the `UserDetails` each time your service is hit.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answers, sorry that I still cannot upvote them.

Finally what I did was to implement an `AuthenticationSuccessHandle` Class, and return it in the `private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler()` method of the existing `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extension Class we had (previously it was returning a `httpServletResponse` using a lambda there, very cool code from a mate), and it looks it's working.
I hope it makes sense.

I have to ensure now the security, as Jun Bach and Andy Brown kindly suggest.

Thanks a lot and cheers